# How to connect two fact tables to one dimensional table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, snowflake-schema

I have two fact tables (HistoricTable, ForecastTable). Both tables use a composite key that combines the productID and WeekID together. The ForecastTable has future weekID's & historic has previous ones. I want both of these ProductID's to reference one Dimensional table called ProductTable. How do I connect them?

My assumption would be to create an additional table that queries HistoricTable & ForecastTable via UNION join and have that connected to the ProductTable. Is this logic correct?

[Table Image Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGGEA.png)

Comment: Why not just foreign key both tables to ProductTable by ProductID? (Please don't give tables names like xyzTable, it's annoying)

Comment: What does "connect them" mean? And why are you trying to do it? What do you mean, a "table that queries"? (A view?) Please ask just 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. How are you 1st stuck following what published design method or writing what code? For code questions give a [mre]. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want both of these ProductID's to reference one Dimensional table called ProductTable.

You can establish one foreign key between `historic` and `product` and another foreign key between `forecast` and `product`.

For example:

```
create table product (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table historic (
  product_id int not null references product (id),
  week_id int not null,
  units_sold int,
  primary key (product_id, week_id)
);

create table forecast (
  product_id int not null references product (id),
  week_id int not null,
  forecast_units int,
  primary key (product_id, week_id)
);
```